# Get notification audio through headset

Tags: notifications, audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Block all sounds going out through speaker when headphone connected](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10996/block-all-sounds-going-out-through-speaker-when-headphone-connected)

I listen to music and audiobooks a lot on my HTC Incredible, and the phone rings through to my headphones, but the notification alert plays through the external speaker.

Is there any way to get it to play through just the headset like the phone ringer does?

Android version 2.2

Comment: IIRC cyanogenmod provides this feature