# Block all sounds going out through speaker when headphone connected

Tags: audio, headphones, samsung-galaxy-551, speakerphone

I'm kind of new in Android and I realized that all the sounds are going out through the speaker regardless if the headphones are connected. If they are the sound also goes out through the headphones, but I'd also like to avoid the speaker when headphones connected.

Is that possible?

Few more information that may help:

- My phone is a Samsung Galaxy i5510
- Its Android 2.2 Froyo
- I've installed Tasker, maybe there is some way to make a profile to achieve what I want.

Thanks, Diego

**Update**

As it wasn't to clear I'll clarify for each sound (if i forget any please let me know):

- Phone calls: Speaker and headphones.
- Notifications: Speaker and headphones.
- Games and almost every app: Only headphones. (I wrote "almost every app" because, for example, Skype or Camera sounds in both speaker and headphones).
- Keyboard and "touch clicks": Headphones.

Summarizing the problem are: phone calls, notifications and some "random" apps.

Comment: What sounds are still going through the speaker? Music, ring tones, notifications, keyboard click, games, something else?

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: That's weird. When my headphones are in _nothing_ comes out through the loudspeaker.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently you can't disable notifications via speakers while still having them via headphones. There's an [open issue for that](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6696).

You also can use [Llama](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.kebab.Llama) or [Tasker](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) to switch profiles when you plug your headphones.

Comment: I'm using Tasker and PhoneWeaver. But still, would like to hear notifications through speakers, instead of silence the phone.

Answer (score 2):

I saw you had another question about Cyanogenmod, and thought I'd point out that it has the option "Always play on speaker" for notifications, ringtones and alarms (in `Settings -> CyanogenMod Settings -> Sound`). So as soon as it's stable (if it's developed further) it can solve most of your problems.

Comment: Nice, so if one disabled this options, the whole alarm stream will only be audible within the headphones if they are connected?

Comment: @Flow Yep, exactly.

Comment: @onik, thanks for the answer. I'll keep this in mind if sometime I install CyanogenMod, but right now there is no official release for my phone and I'm a little afraid of the issues of the unofficial version.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid, but this doesn't seem possible. There once was an method called [setRouting()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setRouting%28int,%20int,%20int%29) in the AudioManager API, but it is nowadays a deprecated method [which simply does nothing.](http://www.google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/media/java/android/media/AudioManager.java&q=AudioManager%20package%3aAndroid&l=1035) I am even not sure if the method would be capable of routing all audio streams only to the (wired) headset.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Lesser AudioSwitch (Google Play)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nordskog.LesserAudioSwitch). It allows a user to force all audio through the speakers, headphones (3.5mm jack), or Bluetooth. It is updated for Android Oreo.

I quote from the description:

> **(Lesser AudioSwitch)**
>
> Switching to headphones will mute all audio to the speakers (Android
>   Oreo and below), including alarms and notifications. This can be
>   disabled in the options.
>
> Includes an Auto-Switch option to automatically switch when headset is
>   connected or disconnected. Also works for Bluetooth.
>
> Bluetooth and switching to headset microphone can be enabled in the
>   settings.

I use Lesser AudioSwitch to force an alarm to sound through my Bluetooth speakers alone and it works beautifully.