# Routing ringtone through headset

Tags: ringtone

I just bought a Samsung Galaxy S8+. Everything is working great, but there is one little thing I can't seem to figure out and that is the ringtone uses only the speakers.

Can I route the ringtone through a headset when it is connected?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there's no way to do that presently. There's a very [old question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10996/block-all-sounds-going-out-through-speaker-when-headphone-connected?rq=1) here that tried achieving it in Android 2.2. You can try setting up Tasker to do it for you. Android doesn't have anything built in for this as far I know.

Comment: I suspected as much. Thank you for your response. I will look into Tasker.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever resolve your question?
It appears that [Samsung Sound Assistant](https://galaxystore.samsung.com/detail/com.samsung.android.soundassistant?session_id=W_0fd5781eac22feaf4ac1f3a81a1ab775) can do what you want.

However, you might want to check [my question about this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/239503/galaxy-note20-ultra-play-ringtone-through-headphones) - just so you are aware of the problem I am having.